# Local notification does not appear after second close of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I need so show local notification right after user closes app (swipe up).

For that purpose I have such code:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self showNotificationAboutClosingApp];
}
```

and

```
- (void) showNotificationAboutClosingApp {

    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = @"test title";
    content.body = @"test body";
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.defaultSound;

    NSString *requestIdentifier = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    NSDate *fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10.0];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian] components:kCFCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:fireDate];
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:false];
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:requestIdentifier content:content trigger:trigger];

    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:nil];
}
```

There is strange behavior: 
First time I launch app, close it (swipe up) -> notification appears in 10 seconds. But after I reopen app and do the same, I mean close app through swipe up, there is no notification after 10 seconds. What I found - if I delete app from iPhone, turn off and turn on iPhone again, install app, close app through swipe up - notification appears.

Any ideas what is wrong in my approach?

**Update:**

Following the advice of @MojtabaHosseini I led my code to this kind:

```
//This class is the place where I prepare all stuff.
@objc class ClosingAppNotificationRequestProvider: NSObject {

    @objc public static let shared = ClosingAppNotificationRequestProvider()
    @objc public private(set) var closingAppNotificationRequest: UNNotificationRequest!
    @objc public static var requestIdentifier: String {
        get {
            return UUID().uuidString
        }
    }

    private override init() {}

    @objc public func initialize() {

        closingAppNotificationRequest = createClosingAppNotificationRequest()
    }

    private func createClosingAppNotificationRequest() -> UNNotificationRequest {

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "some title";
        content.body = "some body";
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: ClosingAppNotificationRequestProvider.requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        return request
    }
}
```

Then init request

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  [[ClosingAppNotificationRequestProvider shared] initialize];
}
```

And when app terminates:

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

  UNNotificationRequest *closingAppNotificationRequest = [[ClosingAppNotificationRequestProvider shared] closingAppNotificationRequest];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:closingAppNotificationRequest withCompletionHandler:nil];
}
```

But indeed result the same.

Comment: I think it's because app closes before your code running completed. Try prepare all stuff somewhere earlier and just call `addNotificationRequest` inside your method to boost execution time.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini can you check my update?